# Proxy CONNECT aborted due to timeout PHP curl

Tags: curl, php

Частенько появляется ошибка:

> > Proxy CONNECT aborted due to timeout

Как исправить?

```
  $ch = curl_init($url);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, '');

  if($params) {
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 
    'X-Insta-Forwarded-For: '.$x_forwarded_for
   ));
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
  }

  // PROXY
  if($proxy) {
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
  }

  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  $error = curl_error($ch);

  return (($error) ? array('error_type' => 'curl', 'error_text' => $error) : $result);

  curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как исправить?

Честно говоря, мне уже больно видеть этот вопрос. Исправить - никак. Не использовать подвисающий прокси. Бить N раз в цикле, пока запрос не пройдет или N не исчерпается. Но исправить - никак.

```
 return (($error) ? array('error_type' => 'curl', 'error_text' => $error) : $result);
```

Из шести скобок на самом деле нужны только две

> // PROXY

Этот комментарий тоже описывает абсолютно очевидное. А вот почему `X-Insta-Forwarded-For` выставляется в случае наличия `$params` - ни разу не очевидно.